# Reading a character from a file out of order in the C language

Tags: c, file

I need to read commands from a file with the following arguments:

```
get_c cmin=NUMBER cmax=NUMBER m=NUMBER
```

That is, you need to extract the NUMBER values ​​​​from the file and place them in the cmin1, cmax1, m1 variables for further manipulations. I came up with this reading option that does its job:

```
for (int y = 0; y < 5; y++) {
    getc(input);
}
fscanf(input, "%llu", &cmin1);
for (int y = 0; y < 6; y++) {
    getc(input);
}
fscanf(input, "%llu", &cmax1);
for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
    getc(input);
}
fscanf(input, "%llu", &m1);
get_c(cmin1, cmax1, m1, output);
fclose(output);
```

But what if the order of the arguments is not strictly regulated and can be anything? The length of the line with the command is not regulated, the line can be arbitrarily long.

Comment: What does the file look like. What type of values are `NUMBER` supposed to be? Why are you using loops that count from `0` to `4`, `5` and `2` respectively? This all makes little sense to me.

Comment: You can use `strtok()` to split the line by spaces, and the split each of those by `=` to get the keyword followed by NUMBER. Then compare the keyword and assign the appropriate variable.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if i understand correctly, but my first idea is to read whole line to a buffer and then find your keywords using  `strstr` which finds given substring. Then you will have pointer to your keyword and all you need is to get your value.